# How can I center my button on radiogroup?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-button, radio-group

I'm at the beginning with android and this is my app. I inserted a radio group on the bottom to build a semi-transparent bar with four buttons, and what I ask to you is, how can I center them?

[image: my app]

and this is my layout xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map_relative_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="0dp"
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingRight="0dp"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.91" />

<RadioGroup 
    android:id="@+id/radio_group_list_selector"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#80000000"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/buttonmuseum"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="" 
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/museum"/> 



    <View 
        android:id="@+id/VerticalLine"
        android:layout_width="1dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#aaa" />


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/buttonhotel"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text=""
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/hotel" />


    <View 
        android:id="@+id/VerticalLine1"
        android:layout_width="1dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#aaa" />


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/buttonrestaurant"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text=""
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/restaurant" />



    <View 
        android:id="@+id/VerticalLine2"
        android:layout_width="1dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#aaa" />


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/buttonsouvenir"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="" 
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/souvenir"/>



</RadioGroup>


</FrameLayout>
```

Any suggestions are accepted. Thank you so much.

P.S.: I designed the red square with paint only to show better the interested area to you.

Comment: try my answer then tell me it worked or not ?

Comment: @Darkie done I already answered you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this add following in radiogroup tag

```
android:gravity="center"
```

Comment: it give me this error: "error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout' with value 'center')."

Comment: ok now they're centered but I also want that the have auto-space between buttons. Now they're at center but all near like in the screenshot. I also want that they are auto-space to auto-adapt to all screens. Have you understand ?

Comment: @PierpaoloErcoli then you should give padding to them like 5dp so they will have spaces

Comment: @PierpaoloErcoli yes or first try to give it in radio group if it work there then it's good else then on every image button

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62323/discussion-between-pierpaolo-ercoli-and-darkie).